# Given a transaction hash, how do you get the block the transaction was included in?

Tags: transactions, blockchain.info, api

I'm using Blockchain.info's api:

https://blockchain.info/api/blockchain_api

I understand that it is impossible for a transaction to know which block it will be included in but maybe one could use the block height to match the tx to the block?

Answer (score 1):

> but maybe one could use the block height to match the tx to the block?

Indeed that would work fine, `block_height` is returned by the /rawtx/ call (https://blockchain.info/rawtx/$tx_hash) for transactions that have been included in a block (unconfirmed transactions have no block_height key). Then you can find the block hash and/or information about the block with the /block-height/ call (https://blockchain.info/block-height/$block_height?format=json)

Comment: Would you mind trying tx hash: 4c1df235ffd7642008989422aee5255e6312b4172b55d94e328fa99e99d727c7 on https://www.smartbit.com.au/api just as a sanity check because I don't see the tx come up on the block it's supposed to...